# kubectl fails to fetch Argocd resource of type Application when kubectl inside a container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, argocd

We have a gke cluster and we have installed ArgoCD on it. When we run the command locally to get applications:
`kubectl get applications -n argocd` the list of Application resources can be seen.

Then, when we try to run `gke-deploy apply` on our ArgoCD config, the apply fails saying that fetching a certain application failed. But when we run the apply locally using `kubectl`, which `gke-deploy` is using under the hood, it successfully applies the argo config.

We have checked the permissions for both the environments by running `kubectl auth can-i get applications -n argocd` and both returns `Yes`.

It might be worth mentioning that we were using `gke-deploy` in our cloudbuild argocd build and we started facing this issue almost out of nowhere.

We thought that this might be because of the latest image version (since we had not specified the version tag for our `gke-deploy` image. But trying tags like `master`, `stable` and a hashed version did not help as well.

Since we are not sure which tool could be responsible for this issue, hence posting here.

Edit 1:
The command in question is: `kubectl get applications -n argocd`. Only our local (non-containerized) env, the command outputs the list of argocd applications. But when the same command is executed from within the aforementioned containers, the output is simply `No resources found in argocd namespace.`.

Comment: What's the exact command that's failing and the actual error message?

Comment: @GariSingh the post has been updated to answer your query.